# Okta SSO on a iOS (across apps restarts and between apps)

Tags: ios, oauth, single-sign-on, okta, appauth

I am experimenting with Okta and the [okta-openidconnect-appauth-ios](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-openidconnect-appauth-ios) test program (project name OpenIDConnectSwift) to see how Okta SSO works on iOS 11. This app leverages the AppAuth library for OIDC.

I have set up the test program and was able to log in and get tokens (auth token, refresh token, ID token), as well as see the user info, etc.

However, when I restart the app or try to do the same thing from another app linked to the same clientID, I only see the username field filled in, and password is blank.

I was under the impression that I should be seeing SSO (meaning I don’t have to re-enter in my password) in these cases because there is some cookie(s) stored globally (accessible via SFAuthenticationSession on iOS 11)

Is there something I need to specially configure to support this? Ideally I want to test OIDC flow, but any other flow is fine if I can achieve SSO across apps and app restart.

Rather than write an app to do this from scratch, I am hoping to use this test app (with minor tweaks and/or configuration changes), or find another app that can demonstrate SSO on iOS 11 using Okta.

UPDATE: I am still seeing issues on 11.2.5, has anyone got this to work?